# ASP.NET Entity Framework issue: one-to-one, two objects mapping to same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluent

My ASP.NET MVC (.NET Core Framework 1.0) code consists of two models:

```
public class BusLine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("RouteA")]
    public int RouteAId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("RouteB")]
    public int? RouteBId { get; set; }

    public virtual BusLineRoute RouteA { get; set; }

    public virtual BusLineRoute RouteB { get; set; }
}

public class BusLineRoute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BusLine")]
    public int BusLineId { get; set; }

    public virtual BusLine BusLine { get; set; }
}
```

`BusLine` model has to have one `BusLineRoute` object, and may contain one more optional `BusLineRoute`.

Unfortunately this way of using data annotations doesn't work, running gives this error:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'BusLine.RouteA' of type 'BusLineRoute'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.
```

I have tried using Fluent API this way:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    (...)

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<BusLine>().HasOne(a => a.RouteA).WithOne(b => b.BusLine);
    builder.Entity<BusLine>().HasOne(a => a.RouteB).WithOne(b => b.BusLine);
}

}
```

Then I got another error:

```
(...) value cannot be null. Parameter name: builder.
```

`builder` is object of `ModelBuilder` class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are your writing that code? Do you have a builder object at that point?

Comment: yes, I changed code now, look

Comment: Is that inside a class which is derived from `DbContext`

Comment: yes, in automatically generated ApplicationDbContext

Comment: @MarcinZdunek : one question does this bus have only 2 routes ? What if more ? Doesnt it make sense to have ICollection<BusLineRoute > instead of 2 ? If that is fine I can show you that solution ?

Comment: I need exactly 1 or 2 routes assigned to bus line, so why use ICollection for 1 or 2 objects?